# QT4 incomplete getting website content

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm trying to write a small test using QHttp to get an URL and return its content.

The program ran fine, but it has some problem.

With this link http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?ztyniqhd4lb ( or some random MF link ), my program cannot load all its content.

With some workaround, I found that all the SIGNAL before the done(bool) is emitted, including the last dataReadProgress,  stateChanged and the last requestFinished. The last SIGNAL requestFinished didn't generate any error.

my code looks like this ( it's quite long with some slots, so I only write the main http call here, url is QUrl("http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?ztyniqhd4lb")

```
http.setHost(url.host(), url.port(80));
http.get(url.path()+ QString("?") + url.queryItems ()[0].first, &file);
http.close();
```

the SIGNAL done(bool) never be emitted, any other SIGNAL before it was fine.

Thanks for any help

Comment: solved myself by using QNetworkAccessManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to say that QHttp is deprecated. You should use QNetworkAccessManager.